# Memory Usage - iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management

I was wondering, what is the most accurate way to test how much memory my game application is using on the device? I've been using Instruments with Allocations and Leaks, but the highest it has ever been is 2.22MB (don't get me wrong I'm not complaining at all).  Is that accurate? Is that even possible for a game? I use A LOT of images (mostly sprite sheets). Also, when I test it in the simulator it says my application is using 22MB+. I'm just confused. I thought it would be either using the same amount on an actual device or more.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your app on the device with the Activity Monitor instrument. That should give you an accurate reading of memory usage.

Comment: Thank you. Just ran it in Activity monitor and it get's up to 19MB when finding an opponent on Game Center and a little over 17MB in actual game play.